# How to append to a list with a specific format

Tags: python, list, append

I would like to give to the program some information like this:

```
['R', 'S', 'S', 'I', 'Q', 'A', 'I', 'T', 'K', 'Q', 'O', 'E', 'F', 'I', 'E', 'S', 'T', 'A', 'D', B', 'M', 'X', 'F', 'E', 'O', 'K', 'I]
```

and I need it to return with a format like :

```
grid = [['R', 'S', 'S', 'I', 'Q', 'A', 'S', 'T', 'K'],
        ['Q', 'O', 'E', 'A', 'I', 'E', 'S', 'T', 'A'],
        ['D', 'B', 'M', 'X', 'F', 'E', 'O', 'K', 'I']]
```

I don't know to append specifically like this.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you determine how many rows and columns should be in the matrix?

Comment: Please explain how the input is related to the output.

Comment: Length of input and ouput are diferent, the same for content. What the relationship ?

Comment: I gave a wrong example, the first line of code has total of 27 elements. I want them to be iterated and then added to the list like that format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below approach. Basically what you want is a list of lists.

`a =['R', 'S', 'S', 'I', 'Q', 'A', 'I', 'T', 'K']`

`b=['Q', 'O', 'E', 'F', 'I', 'E', 'S', 'T', 'A']`

`c=['B', 'M', 'X', 'F', 'E', 'O', 'R']`

`d=[a,b,c]`

`print(d)`
`

Comment: Except I need to iterate through all of the elements in the list and then append it to the format like it. Sorry the total number of elements in the first line of code is supposed to be 27 elements. So that it forms 3 rows of 9 elements.

Comment: @HarishPalanivel if you need to return it only you can use `print(*np.array_split(a, 3))` where a is the list

Comment: Sorry, I am just learning to program. Thank you for your support. It actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `list.append` method by giving it a list of elements.

```
grid = []   
grid.append(['R', 'S', 'S', 'I', 'Q', 'A', 'S', 'T', 'K'])
grid.append(['Q', 'O', 'E', 'A', 'I', 'E', 'S', 'T', 'A'])
```

and so forth.